# Java split() как поделить строку на запятые и пробелы?

Tags: java, split

> *( int sayi ,int sayi2 ,int sayi3,string laf) <- txt файл*.

мне нужно split()-ом по отдельности переместить слова в какой-нибудь массив string.Например использую

> `String[] dizi=metin.split("\\s+|,\\s*");`

metin-это string в котором содержится строка ниже

> ( int sayi ,int sayi2 ,int sayi3,string laf)

Но на экран выдает это

> [int, sayi, , int, sayi2, , int, sayi3, string, laf]

мне нужно чтоб выдавало

> [int,sayi,int,sayi2,int,sayi3,string,laf]

чтоб пробелы тоже обходил,в данный момент например когда ввожу

> `System.out.print(dizi[0]);`

на экран выводит пустоту как сделать чтоб пустоты в массив не добавляла

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String[] dizi = Arrays.stream(metin.split(","))
                      .map(String::trim)
                      .map(i -> i.split(" "))
                      .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
                      .toArray(String[]::new);
```

или так

```
Pattern delimiters = Pattern.compile(",|\\s");
String[] dizi = delimiters.splitAsStream(metin)
                          .filter(i -> i.length() > 0)
                          .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Answer (score 1):

Поделить на пробелы элементарно:

```
String[] dizi = metin.split(" ");
```

В этом случае в массиве будут лежать слова, из которых состоит строка

Comment: но запятые остаются,мне надо чтоб и на пробелы и на запятые делила

Comment: @Kenan, просто укажите нужную строку-разделитель. Т.е. так: `String[] dizi = metin.split(" ,");`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб у него два разделителя - пробел и запятая. Причём пробел может быть слева от запятой, справа, с обеих сторон или может отсутствовать. Подозреваю, что несколько пробелов подряд тоже быть может.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, а, тогда, да, тут всё сложнее)